# strip packing problem with fixed x-coordinate

Tags: optimization, packing, memory-allocation

Similar to the classic 2D strip packing problem, we want to put N blocks into a 2d strip and minimize the height of the strip. Each block has to be put at the **fixed x-coordinate**. **The width and height of all blocks are integer**.

Below is an example of 4 blocks:

[image]

you can only move every block **up and down** to reduce the overrall height. And a possible solution can be:

[image]

This problem originated from a memory allocation problem. For a computer, there are N known processes. Their start time and memory usage are different. We need to allocate memory properly to minimize the **peak** memory usage.

Does anyone have any clue to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same as the [register allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) problem, so I would guess that you might be able to use the same techniques.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to the problem of finding the [chromatic number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) of an [interval graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph). This can be done by a greedy algorithm: sort the blocks in ascending order (after left endpoint) and, for each block, put it on the lowest level where there is room for it.

Comment: thanks! It is a nice problem transformation : )